# Issue with SQL query with join of 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables in my SQL Server (`Dorig` and `Dotes`) that are connected by column `id_dotes` present in both.

I need a help for a query that returns a result of `Dorig` with column `NumeroDocRif`, present only in table `Dotes`, where this last one must to be extracted when this condition is true

```
dorig.id_dorig = dorig.id_dorig_evade
```

I try to create this query but it doesn't work completely well:

```
SELECT 
    dorig.Id_Dorig, dotes.NumerodocRif
FROM 
    dorig
LEFT JOIN 
    dotes ON dotes.id_Dotes = dorig.id_Dotes
WHERE 
    id_dorig IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_dorig_evade 
                 FROM dorig 
                 WHERE id_dotes = dorig.id_dotes)
```

Could you please help me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: welcome to SO, but please edit your question, in current state its quality does not match the guideline, please include Sample data, Expect output, clear logic written in plain text, and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). also with `sql` tag you should always also tag your DBMS (e.g. Oracle, Sql-server), visit [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: plz share sample data and output

Comment: Are you simply looking for `WHERE id_dorig = id_dorig_evade`?

Comment: "It doesn't work completely well" doesn't tell us anything. Does it return too many rows? Too few? Do you get a runtime error? You should show some sample data, the expected result and explain how your query is different from what you expect. And what DBMS are you asking this for? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question.

Comment: Your `JOIN` statement will already ensure that only records will show where both `id_notes` are equal. So you can already select from `dorig` the relevant unique `dorig_evades`? The last `WHERE` clause seems to be redundant as the `id_dotes` will be equal as a result of the join? Unless you need the join to apply to the `IN(...)` clause as well. In which case you need to include the `JOIN` in the subquery as well? (The subquery is the portion in your `IN(...)` statement. As the first `JOIN` only applies to to encapsulating statement, it does not apply to the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create table dorig (id_dorig int, id_dotes int, id_dorig_evade int);

 create table dotes(id_dotes int, numerodocrif varchar(50));




insert into dorig values(16934,3116,4894);
insert into dorig values(4894,1090,null);
insert into dotes values(1090,'7000079957');


SELECT d.Id_Dorig,d.id_dotes,dt.NumerodocRif
  FROM dorig d inner join dorig dg
  on d.id_dorig_evade =dg.id_dorig
  inner JOIN dotes dt ON dt.id_Dotes = dg.id_Dotes
```

| Id_Dorig | id_dotes | NumerodocRif |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16934 | 3116 | 7000079957 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=266ec6e37e95f04f916f425b8f7690a8)*

Comment: Could you please share sample data?

Comment: I've just added it in answer above

Comment: Would you please check my revised answer.

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: I see your query above but the results is not correct...I need to have this result: ID_DORIG 16934 ID_DOTES 3116 NumeroDocRif 7000079957

Comment: I used SQL Server

Comment: got you. I have revised my answer

Comment: You are most welcome. If it works please accept the answer by clicking green check.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like all you should need to do is replace the statement you already wrote out in the text of your question into your second `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT dorig.Id_Dorig,dotes.NumerodocRif
  FROM dorig
  LEFT JOIN dotes ON dotes.id_Dotes = dorig.id_Dotes
  WHERE id_dorig IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT id_dorig_evade FROM dorig 
      WHERE dorig.id_dorig = dorig.id_dorig_evade)
```

Comment: I have no results with this query

Comment: Try
`SELECT DISTINCT id_dorig_evade FROM dorig WHERE dorig.id_dorig = dorig.id_dorig_evade`
Does it return any results? If not, then `dorig.id_dorig = dorig.id_dorig_evade` is never true in your data.